# maximum size of a $k$-intersecting family of $[n]$

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

> 1. What is the maximum size of a family of subsets of $[n]:=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ say $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mid A\cap B\mid \ge k$ where
>      $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$ and $1\le k\le n-1$?

This not [Erdos-ko-rado theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem). In Erdos-ko-rado theorem, we place an extra restriction that subsets of $\mathcal{A}$ have to be of same size.

My idea:

> There are $2^{n-k}$ subsets of $\{k+1,k+2,\dots ,n\}$. Append $\{1,2,\dots ,k\}$ to each of these sets. Hence, $2^{n-k}$ is a lower bound. Is it possibly the maximum we are seeking?

With some change:

> 2 Let $C$ be the set of subsets of $[n]$ such that size of each subset does not exceed $r$. What is the maximum size of a family of subsets from $C$ (say $\mathcal{B}$) such that $\mid A\cap B\mid \ge k$ where
>   $A,B\in \mathcal{B}$ and $1\le k\le r$?

Comment: Related to: [833017](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833017/maximum-size-of-a-k-intersecting-antichain-of-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is known as *Katonas Theorem*.

We use the following notation: Let $\mathcal{N}$ be the set of positive integers, $[i,j]=\{i,i+1,\dots,j\}$ for $i,j \in \mathcal{N}, [n] = [1,n]$ and for $k<n$ let $2^{[n]}=\{A:A\subset[n]\}$ be the unrestricted subsets of $[n]$.

A system of sets $\mathcal{A}\subset 2^{[n]}$ is called *k-intersecting*, if $|A_1 \cap A_2| \geq k$ for all $A_1,A_2\in \mathcal{A}$.

> Theorem (*Katona $1964$*):
>
> Let $I(n,k)$ denote the set of all $k$-intersecting systems and $M(n,k)=max_{\mathcal{A}\in I(n,k)}|\mathcal{A}|$. The following statement is valid
>
> \begin{equation*}
> M(n,k)=
> \begin{cases}\sum_{j=\frac{n+k}{2}}^{n}\binom{n}{j},&2 \mid (n+k)\\
> &\\
> 2\sum_{j=\frac{n+k-1}{2}}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j},&2 \nmid (n+k)
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation*}

The answer above together with a *really short* proof can be found in the paper *[Katona's intersection theorem: Four proofs](http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/ahlswede/homepage/public/179.pdf)*, from *R. Ahlswede* and *L. H. Khachatrian*.

*Note:* An interesting overview with answers to your and related questions can be found in *[Intersecting families of sets and permutations: a survey](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.6144.pdf)* from Peter Borg ($2011$).

> **Added 2014-07-19:** I've added below a table and examples for small values $M(n,k)$ with $n \leq 6$ to provide a first impression which $k$-intersecting families $\mathcal{A}$ have size $|\mathcal{A}| > 2^{n-k}$.

The interesting values $M(n,k) > 2^{n-k}$ $(2\leq n \leq 6$ and $1 \leq k \leq n-1)$ are written $\bf{bold}$.

> **$M(n,k)$:**
>
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{crrrrr}
> n/k&1&2&3&4&5\\
> \hline\\
> 2&2\\
> 3&4&2\\
> 4&8&\bf{5}&2\\
> 5&16&\bf{10}&\bf{6}&2\\
> 6&32&\bf{22}&\bf{12}&\bf{7}&2
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}

The following four examples are simply for illustration. For $$(n,k)\in\{(4,2),(5,2),(5,3),(6,2)\}$$ a family $\mathcal{A}_1$ according to the appoach of [talegari](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/27440/talegari) with $|\mathcal{A}_1|=2^{n-k}$ elements and a family $\mathcal{A}_2$ with $|\mathcal{A}_2|=M(n,k) > 2^{n-k}$ is listed.

---

Example: $n=4,k=2$

> $|\mathcal{A}_1|=2^{4-2}=4$, $|\mathcal{A}_2|=M(4,2)=5$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{rl}
> \mathcal{A}_1=&\{\{1,2\},\\
> &\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4\}\}\\
> \end{array}
> \qquad
> \begin{array}{rl}
> \mathcal{A}_2=&\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4\}\}\\
> \\
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}

Example: $n=5,k=2$

> $|\mathcal{A}_1|=2^{5-2}=8$, $|\mathcal{A}_2|=M(5,2)=10$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{rl}
> \mathcal{A}_1=&\{\{1,2\},\\
> &\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,5\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,5\},\{1,2,4,5\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4,5\}\}\\
> \end{array}
> \begin{array}{rl}
> \mathcal{A}_2=&\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,5\},\{1,2,4,5\},\\
> &\{1,3,4,5\},\{2,3,4,5\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4,5\}\}\\
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}

Example: $n=5,k=3$

> $|\mathcal{A}_1|=2^{5-3}=4$, $|\mathcal{A}_2|=M(5,3)=6$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{rl}
> \mathcal{A}_1=&\{\{1,2,3\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,5\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4,5\}\}\\
> \end{array}
> \begin{array}{rl}
> \mathcal{A}_2=&\{\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,5\},\{1,2,4,5\},\\
> &\{1,3,4,5\},\{2,3,4,5\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4,5\}\}\\
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}

Example: $n=6,k=2$

> $|\mathcal{A}_1|=2^{6-2}=16$, $|\mathcal{A}_2|=M(6,2)=22$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{A}_1=\{&\{1,2\},\\
> &\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,5\},\{1,2,6\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,5\},\{1,2,3,6\},\\
> &\{1,2,4,5\},\{1,2,4,6\},\{1,2,5,6\}\\
> &\{1,2,3,4,5\},\{1,2,3,4,6\},\{1,2,3,5,6\},\{1,2,4,5,6\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}\\
> \\
> \mathcal{A}_2=\{&\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,5\},\{1,2,3,6\},\{1,2,4,5\},\{1,2,4,6\},\\
> &\{1,2,5,6\},\{1,3,4,5\},\{1,3,4,6\},\{1,3,5,6\},\{1,4,5,6\},\\
> &\{2,3,4,5\},\{2,3,4,6\},\{2,3,5,6\},\{2,4,5,6\},\{3,4,5,6\},\\
> &\{1,2,3,4,5\},\{1,2,3,4,6\},\{1,2,3,5,6\},\\
> &\{1,2,4,5,6\},\{1,3,4,5,6\},\{2,3,4,5,6\}\\
> &\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: @talegari: Thanks for the bounty! I've added some small examples for better illustration. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could not have asked for more.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the classical problems in Extremal Set Theory, with Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem addressing the simplest case. Infact, as per my knowledge, this was the problem Erdos had in mind. Ofcourse there is no simple combinatorial solution yet(and probably won't be a $simple$ one). [This](http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/ahlswede/homepage/public/122.pdf) paper will shed some light on its complexity.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. Most of the problems discusses in the paper seem to concern the family of subsets from $\binom{[n]}{k}$ and not the set of all subsets.