# Number of intersecting subsets

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that we have a universe $U= \{1,\dots,n\}$ for some integer $n$. How many subsets $S_1,S_2,\dots\subseteq U $ are there such that $S_i \nsubseteq S_j$ but $S_i \cap S_j \neq \emptyset$ for all $i,j$? That means all $S_i$ and $S_j$ pairwise intersect but none are subsets of each other.

I tried starting with one $S_1$ and then counting the number of possible $S_2$ sets using the binomial coefficient but this didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833017/maximum-size-of-a-k-intersecting-antichain-of-n

Answer (score 1):

This is [OEIS sequence A037952](https://oeis.org/A037952), given by

$$
\binom n{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor}\;.
$$

The entry states (without proof) that this is "the maximum size of an intersecting (or proper) antichain on an $n$-set", which is what you're looking for. An example of such an antichain is given by all subsets with $\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor$ elements.

([Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/1a2ae3ba07a0e316d97f31e53b7101a6) I used to find the terms up $n=5$ to search for the sequence in OEIS.)